# Macro behave differently when runs from outside vbs

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I need to unhide the sheet TAB for an open xlsx file, so to do it, I use VBS file to open a xlsm file and activate the macro (located in a module).
when I run the macro manually it works.
when it activated through the vbs it can see only the xlsm file which contains the macro and no other open excel at the moment.

any ideas?
thx

the vbs code:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set book = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\23892\Desktop\restore_ribbon.xlsm")
objExcel.Application.Run "'C:\Users\23892\Desktop\restore_ribbon.xlsm'!Module1.Restore_Ribbons"
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

the macro code:

```
Sub Restore_Ribbons()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim str As String
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    MsgBox wb.Name 'checking if name extracted correctly
    wb.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
    ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
    wb.Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Next Workbook

MsgBox ("End")

End Sub
```

Comment: You are creating an independent application instance with the vbscript. This cannot 'see' the environment of the first application instance, specifically the workbooks collection.

Comment: `CreateObject` creates its own instance of Excel.  If you need to attach to an open instance, use `GetObject`.

Comment: `Set objExcel = GetObject("Excel.Application")` instead of `Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` as mentioned by @Comintern should be a working solution.

Comment: Hi Guys Thanks a lot for the help, it certainly stirred me in the right direction.
the working code i ended up with:

Comment: [Set objExcel = GetObject("C:\restore_ribbon.xlsm")
objExcel.Application.Run "'C:\restore_ribbon.xlsm'!Module1.Restore_Ribbons"
objExcel.Close
Set objExcel = Nothing]

Answer (score 0):

the code again...
thenks again

```
 Set objExcel = GetObject("C:\restore_ribbon.xlsm")
    objExcel.Application.Run "'C:\restore_ribbon.xlsm'!Module1.Restore_Ribbons"
    objExcel.Close
    Set objExcel = Nothing
```